# New to jquery, wondering why .hide() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't really know why this isn't working but I'm new to javascript so I'm sure I made a mistake.

I have a button and when clicked I want the div to disappear but when I click on the button nothing happens.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#begin-button').click(function() {
  $('#welcome-div').hide();
 });
};
```

```html
<div id="welcome-div">
    <p>Welcome</p>
 </div>

<a href="#" id="begin-button" class="intro-button"/>Begin Tour</a>
```

Comment: missing jquery library

Comment: Also a typo missing `)` in closing `});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing jQuery library in your code snippet.Add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to include jQuery library

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#begin-button').click(function() {
        $('#welcome-div').hide();
    });
};
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#begin-button').click(function() {
    $('#welcome-div').hide();
  });
});
//^....... missing ')'
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="welcome-div">
  <p>Welcome</p>
</div>

<a href="#" id="begin-button" class="intro-button" />Begin Tour</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">    
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hide</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
  <style type="text/css">
  label input[type="file"] 
{
display: block;
margin-top: -20px;
opacity: 0;
}
  </style>
  <script>
   $(window).ready(function() {
$(document).delegate('#hide','click',function(){

  $('#spanFileName').hide();
});
});
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<p id='hide'> Click for hide</p>

<span id='spanFileName'>Hide me</span>
</body>
</html>
```